# In ggplot 2, the text size changed when run the same code on anotehr different computer

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

In ggplot2 , the text size of `label / axis.text.x` is suitable . When I run the same code as below  in another computer ,the font size is so big . How to handle it ? Thanks!

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
diamonds %>% group_by(cut) %>% summarise(count= n()) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x= cut,y=count))+geom_col()+
  geom_text(vjust = -1,aes(label = count),size=8)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=expansion(mult=c(0,0.1)))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=16))
```

Comment: I’m guessing the computers have different default graphics devices.  If you export to a .tif or other image or force the same graphics device on both systems they would both produce the same image.

Comment: @Dan Slone  How to  force the same graphics device ? Thanks!

Comment: Each of the entries in ?Devices shows how to call that device.  In RStudio Global Options - General - Graphics, the Backend option can change what device is used to display graphics in a window.   This can sometimes help with weird screen plotting.